# error on oncreate() method

Tags: java, android

I am begginer in Android App and using Java as when I add this code :

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
          GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        } else {
          Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
        }
```

I had error on :
SENDER_ID
Log
TAG

the error "cannot be resolved to available "

Comment: If you're a beginner you shouldn't start with GCM.

Comment: Have you look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html) one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented if you're a beginner you shouldn't start with GCM, but seems that you're a beginner not only on Android but also in Java (this is not bad, everybody was a beginner, and I'm not that advanced).

I suggest you to start following some basic tutorials on Java, then start with some basic tutorial for Android and so on.

GCM requires also a server side, so this is going to be quite advanced.

Anyway, the error is simple. SENDER_ID is a field that you haven't defined anywhere.

You have to declare it somewhere, like:

```
String SENDER_ID = "mySenderId";
```

or at the top of your class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final SENDER_ID = "mySenderID";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your advise , also what about Log and TAG as have the same error

Comment: You need to import the Log class, and you haven't defined `TAG` do that in the same way as defining `SENDER_ID`

Comment: For TAG is the same story, you have to define a custom TAG string do find more easily your infos/errors while debugging. Log is a class used to "log", you have to import (if you didn't) android.util.Log. [edit: Chris was faster!]